# Add a random value of the order of 10^-2 to raster layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, analysis, random, smoothing

I was doing some raster analysis for smoothing in ArcGIS, one of my task is adding a random value of the order of 10^-2 to a raster layer. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a few ways to do this and it depends on the specifics. Are you applying this random value to every raster cell? Does the value change for each cell/are random cells chosen for the random number?

I would either:

Generate a random number using something like the python random module or a random number generator online and then apply it to each raster cell using "Raster Calculator" tool in ArcGIS.

Or:

Export the raster to ascii text file using ArcGIS "Raster to ASCII" tool, read as table or array and iterate through the raster values assigning some to your random number. Then save as new ascii and convert back to raster.

Comment: Oh yeah, and you may need to first convert the raster to floating point values if it isn't already.

Comment: There is a tool Create Random Raster. It is enough to use it and divide result by 100